# Check box isn't checked in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In IE, this code doesn't work; the check box is not checked. In other browsers, it works fine.

```
if (obj != null) {
    $.each(obj, function (i, tabRole) {
        $(":checkbox[value=" + tabRole.TabID+"]").prop("checked", "true");
    });
}
```

Comment: I fixed some of the English and code formatting mistakes in your question. It would be helpful if you were to post what you've tried so far to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(":checkbox[value=" + tabRole.TabID+"]").prop("checked", "checked");
```

instead. The value for the checked attribute in html is checked, not true or false, even if some browsers may support those values.